# How to run task (that changes file) and avoid loop, if this task starts when this file changes

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I have tasks:

- "styles" that compile my Sass code into css
- "watch" that will start "styles" when .sass files changes
- "deafult" that start all tasks

All was ok until I wanted to sort my properties, I have found sass-sort module that works from CLI. I also downloaded gulp-exec module, so i could add command `sortsass ./src/styles/main.sass` to my task `styles`

I tried to take out `.pipe(exec('sortsass ./src/styles/main.sass'))` from "styles", create new task, and add it to "watch" task (so after file changes, tasks "styles" and new task started), the same result. Also tried to google other ways to sort properties in .sass files (style lint works very well with scss, but I am working with sass), tried to find extensions for `vscode` which can do it..

```
    const gulp         = require('gulp');
    const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
    const del          = require('del');
    const imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin')
    const concat       = require('gulp-concat');
    const uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');
    const sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
    const sass         = require('gulp-sass');
    const cleanCSS     = require('gulp-clean-css');
    const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    const exec         = require('gulp-exec');

    gulp.task('clean', function() {
      return del([
        'build/*']);
    });

    gulp.task('markup', function() {
      return gulp.src([
        './src/**/*.html'
      ],  {base: './src/'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });

    gulp.task('styles', function() {
      return gulp.src([
        './src/**/*.sass'
      ],  {base: './src/'}) 
        .pipe(exec('sortsass ./src/styles/main.sass'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({level: 2}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({Browserslist: ['last 2 versions'], cascade: false}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    });

    gulp.task('scripts', function() {
      return gulp.src([
        './src/js/lib.js',
        './src/js/main.js',
      ],  {base: './src/'})
        .pipe(uglify({toplevel: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });

    gulp.task('concat-scripts', function() {
      return gulp.src([
        './build/js/lib.js',
        './build/js/main.js',
      ])
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    })

      gulp.task('images', function() {
        return gulp.src([
          './src/img/**'
        ],  {base: './src/'})
          .pipe(imagemin({progressive: true}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
          .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build/"
        }
      });
      gulp.watch('./src/**/*.html', gulp.series('markup'))
      gulp.watch('./src/**/*.sass', gulp.series('styles'))
      gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', gulp.series('scripts', 'concat-scripts'))
      gulp.watch('./src/**/img/**/*', gulp.series('images'))
    });

    gulp.task('trash', function() {
      return del([
        './build/styles/media.css',
        './build/styles/media.css.map',
        './build/js/lib.js',
        './build/js/main.js',
      ]);
    });

    gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.series('clean',
                                   gulp.parallel('markup',
                                                 'images',
                                                 'styles',
                                                 'scripts')),
                                                 'concat-scripts',
                                                 'trash',
                                                 'watch'))
```

when I start 'default' task:

```
    [19:35:15] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\projects\new\gulpfile.js
    [19:35:15] Starting 'default'...
    [19:35:15] Starting 'clean'...
    [19:35:15] Finished 'clean' after 34 ms
    [19:35:15] Starting 'markup'...
    [19:35:15] Starting 'images'...
    [19:35:15] Starting 'styles'...
    [19:35:15] Starting 'scripts'...
    [19:35:15] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
    [19:35:15] Finished 'images' after 58 ms
    [19:35:15] Finished 'markup' after 61 ms
    [19:35:15] Finished 'scripts' after 61 ms
    [19:35:15] Finished 'styles' after 239 ms
    [19:35:15] Starting 'concat-scripts'...
    [19:35:15] Finished 'concat-scripts' after 9.62 ms
    [19:35:15] Starting 'trash'...
    [19:35:15] Finished 'trash' after 5.4 ms
    [19:35:15] Starting 'watch'...
    [Browsersync] Access URLs:
     ------------------------------------
           Local: http://localhost:3000
        External: http://192.168.0.4:3000
     ------------------------------------
              UI: http://localhost:3001
     UI External: http://localhost:3001
     ------------------------------------
    [Browsersync] Serving files from: ./build/

and when I am changing sass file

    [19:36:46] Starting 'styles'...
    [Browsersync] 4 files changed (main.css.map, main.css, media.css.map, media.css)
    [19:36:47] Finished 'styles' after 264 ms
    [19:36:47] Starting 'styles'...
    [Browsersync] 4 files changed (main.css.map, main.css, media.css.map, media.css)
    [19:36:47] Finished 'styles' after 228 ms
    [19:36:47] Starting 'styles'...
    [Browsersync] 4 files changed (main.css.map, main.css, media.css.map, media.css)
    [19:36:48] Finished 'styles' after 223 ms
    [19:36:48] Starting 'styles'...
    [Browsersync] 4 files changed (main.css.map, main.css, media.css.map, media.css)
    [19:36:48] Finished 'styles' after 207 ms
    [19:36:48] Starting 'styles'...
```

this loop is endless, until i close terminal

So now the real problem more is how to sort properties, then how to avoid loop.. But I will happy with any solution (avoid loop, or another way to sort properties: extensions for vscode, plugins for gulp etc.)

Comment: use webpack:) this one is much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSSComb helped me. Installed it in vscode